# Should I keep or remove Django dynamic models

Tags: django

A project I was dealing now was using https://github.com/dobarkod/django-dynamic-model.

I feel using django south is better so I want to know opinion of experts whether I need to continue using that or replace it with normal migrations?  Also current django version is 1.4, I am not sure if I can easily upgrade to 1.6 or 1.7 with that above app.

Currently huge data in production(like 20,000 records).

I got an issue recently like when I use 'fields' in modelform, it is still printing all fields. If I have to tweak everything just for using a third party app, I dont think it is a useful app. I really dont like this app, any suggestions ?

Comment: What Python version are you using? How big is your project? How big is your use of Dynamic model?

Comment: Python is 2.7, project is big, but not too big. At the max 20-30 models  only.  I am using Dynamic model for about 3 to 5 models only.

Comment: also fields are < 10

Answer (score 0):

If migrations work for you now, I think you should remove Django dynamic models and migrate with no great pain to Django 1.7.

If you liked South, you are gonna be amazed by Django 1.7 which comes with South on the inside, simpler commands and really good-looking-for-source-control-fashioned migrations.

First you will need to remove South migration files from your apps, create an initial migration, keep the dynamic model app on your dependencies and create migrations to convert every dynamic field on a actual field of your (3-5) models via migrations. Also, I think you will need to create [data migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) to import the data you already have on the dynamic model.

Check out Django documentation on [migrating from south](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#upgrading-from-south) for more information.

Upgrading to Django 1.7 from version 1.4 you will get:

1. Access to the latest features of Django (including Custom User
   model, migrations, persistent database connections improvements,
   etc)
2. Less dependencies of your projects (You won't need South and
   Dynamic models app anymore), so it will be easier and faster to
   deploy Faster approach
3. Best performance on your database: You will remove the database joins needed to retrieve the dynamic models, so as your data will live on the same table, your queries related to the dynamic models will take less time to complete.